# Calculate Camera parameters and HandEyeCalibration

Tags: transformations, projections, perspective, camera-matrix, camera

I'm trying to calculate camera paramters and a hand eye calibration (Transformation from camera to eye (display) coordinates) for rendering on a see-through HMD.

I have already calculated a Projection matrix P (using SPAAM) which transforms points in the camera coordinate system to the screen (Tested by custom rendering).

Cause of the used framework (metaio) I can't set the projection matrix directly  but have to separately set the camera parameters and Hand Eye calibration for rendering.

Therefore I have extracted the extrinsic (E) and intrinsic (I) camera parameters from the Projection matrix P.

[image]

But those are not working correctly when set. The result seems to be not completely off, cause the rendered scale seems to be correct.

I guess I'm missing some additional step I'm not aware of or the extrinsics are not the hand-eye-calibration I'm looking for.

I appreciate any ideas and help.

Additional information:

- right handed coordinate system with camera looking in negative z axsis, x to the right and y up
- Since The translation part of HEC on the x- axis has to be positive (known from working configs) (camera is on the right side of the HMD) I assume it's transformation is specified from eye to camera?

PS: Before I realized this stackexchange exist, I have already asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623966/calculate-camera-parameters-and-handeyecalibration). I got unfortunately no feedback so far.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question on multiple sites. It means that any answers get spread across different places, making that information harder to find in future.